# Django query expression for calculated fields that require conditions and casting

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I am trying to run an aggregation query that is roughly equals to:

```
select 
    sum(impressions) as impressions, 
    sum(clicks) as clicks, 
    sum(clicks)/sum(impressions) as ctr 
from stats 
group by product
order by ctr;
```

The database used is PostgreSQL.

I made this query expression (Django 1.9):

```
Stats.objects.values('product').annotate(
    impressions = models.Sum('impressions'), 
    clicks = models.Sum('clicks'), 
    ctr = models.ExpressionWrapper(
        models.F('clicks')/models.F('impressions')), output_field = models.FloatField()
    )
).order_by('ctr')
```

There are 2 problems with it:

- `ctr` is 0.0 because it divides integers at the database level
- it throws `division by zero` if impressions are 0

What is the proper solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, Sum, When

Stats.objects.values('product').annotate(
    tot_impressions=Sum('impressions'), 
    tot_clicks=Sum('clicks')
).annotate(
    ctr=Case(When(tot_impressions=0, then=None),  # or other value, e.g. then=0
             # 1.0*... is to get float in SQL
             default=1.0*F('tot_clicks')/F('tot_impressions'),
             output_field=models.FloatField())
).order_by('ctr')
```

Comment: Works, thanks. Annotation names could be the same btw.

Answer (score 0):

The exact math on how you scale this is up to you, but adding in a python constant inside a nested [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/) should suffice:

```
ctr = models.ExpressionWrapper(
    models.F('clicks')/models.ExpressionWrapper(
        models.F('impressions') + 1, output_field = models.FloatField()
    ),
    output_field = models.FloatField()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `django-pg-utils` [package](https://github.com/hypertrack/django-pg-utils) for the `divide` query expression that handles division by zero and returns float values

```
from pg_utils import divide

Stats.objects.annotate(ctr=divide(F('clicks'), F('impressions')))
```