# Django query expression for calculated fields with aggregation and without grouping

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Continuing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733760/django-query-expression-for-calculated-fields-that-require-conditions-and-castin).

I have the following query expression in Django:

```
fields = {
    'impressions': models.Sum('impressions'), 
    'clicks': models.Sum('clicks'), 
}
calc_fields = {
    'ctr': models.Case(models.When(impressions = 0, then = 0), default = 1.0 * models.F('clicks') / models.F('impressions'), output_field = models.FloatField()),
}

Stats.objects.values('product').annotate(**fields).annotate(**calc_fields)
```

This correctly calculates aggregated fields `impressions`, `clicks` and `ctr` grouped by `product` and produces the following postgres query:

```
SELECT 
    "stats"."product_id", 
    SUM("stats"."impressions") AS "impressions", 
    SUM("stats"."clicks") AS "clicks", 
    CASE WHEN SUM("stats"."impressions") = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ((1.0 * SUM("stats"."clicks")) / SUM("stats"."impressions")) END AS "ctr" 
FROM "stats" 
GROUP BY "stats"."product_id";
```

**Now all I want is to modify this expression so when no grouping is provided it would just return aggregated values across the whole table.**

And it appears to be harder than I expected. The rest of the question can be skipped, I'm just listing what I've tried.

1) First attempt to just drop `values()`:

```
Stats.objects.annotate(**fields).annotate(**calc_fields)
```

This produces an error:

```
The annotation 'impressions' conflicts with a field on the model.
```

This happens probably because it now tries to return a list of full `Stats` objects with all its fields rather than only custom fields I've listed as before. Maybe there is a way to disable it and just return custom fields?

I tried renaming the fields but it results in grouping by the primary index, so it returns all records in the table rather than one

2) Maybe I need to swap annotate with aggregate.

```
Stats.objects.aggregate(**fields).aggregate(**calc_fields)
```

This produces an error:

```
Error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'aggregate'
```

Ok maybe they cannot be chained, lets merge the fields together and swap `F` with `Sum` inside the case:

```
fields = {
    'impressions': models.Sum('impressions'), 
    'clicks': models.Sum('clicks'), 
    'ctr': models.Case(models.When(impressions = 0, then = 0), default = 1.0 * models.Sum('clicks') / models.Sum('impressions'), output_field = models.FloatField()),
}

Stats.objects.aggregate(**fields)
```

This appears to be working correctly. But the hell breaks loose again when I add extra fields (all values are the same, only names are different):

```
fields = {
    'impressions': models.Sum('impressions'), 
    'impressions2': models.Sum('impressions'), 
    'clicks': models.Sum('clicks'), 
    'clicks2': models.Sum('clicks'), 
    'ctr': models.Case(models.When(impressions = 0, then = 0), default = 1.0 * models.Sum('clicks') / models.Sum('impressions'), output_field = models.FloatField()),
    'ctr2': models.Case(models.When(impressions = 0, then = 0), default = 1.0 * models.Sum('clicks') / models.Sum('impressions'), output_field = models.FloatField()),
}
```

It seems that the problem is caused by multiple `models.When(impressions = 0)`, it generates wrong sql:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN "stats"."impressions" = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ((1.0 * SUM("stats"."clicks")) / SUM("stats"."impressions")) END AS "ctr", 
    CASE WHEN SUM("fstats"."impressions") = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ((1.0 * SUM("stats"."clicks")) / SUM("impressions")) END AS "ctr2", 
    SUM("stats"."impressions") AS "impressions", 
    SUM("stats"."impressions") AS "impressions2", 
    SUM("stats"."clicks") AS "clicks",
    SUM("stats"."clicks") AS "clicks2", 
FROM "stats";
```

Notice how the CASE for `ctr` is incorrectly calculated as:

```
CASE WHEN "stats"."impressions" = 0
```

While for `ctr2` it is correct:

```
CASE WHEN SUM("stats"."impressions") = 0
```

Which causes the database error:

```
column "stats.impressions" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

3) Renaming all aggregated fields to be different from model fields so there is no chance of confusion:

```
fields = {
    'impressions_total': models.Sum('impressions'), 
    'impressions_total2': models.Sum('impressions'), 
    'clicks_total': models.Sum('clicks'), 
    'clicks_total2': models.Sum('clicks'), 
    'ctr': models.Case(models.When(impressions_total = 0, then = 0), default = 1.0 * models.Sum('clicks') / models.Sum('impressions'), output_field = models.FloatField()),
    'ctr2': models.Case(models.When(impressions_total = 0, then = 0), default = 1.0 * models.Sum('clicks') / models.Sum('impressions'), output_field = models.FloatField()),
}

Stats.objects.aggregate(**fields)
```

This produces error:

```
Error: Cannot resolve keyword 'impressions_total' into field. Choices are: clicks, clicks_total, impressions, impressions_total2, product, product_id
```

If I leave single `ctr` without `ctr2` it works fine. Again adding extra fields breaks it for some reason.

Any tips? I would prefer it to just return an array of custom fields rather than full objects.

Comment: I've skipped the rest of the question. I am under the impression the `impressions` field is part of the model/record, therefore clashing with the annotation, as you point out. If that is the case, have you tried changing the name of the annotated field to something else? e.g. `fields = { 'imprex': models.Sum('impressions'),..`

Comment: @Pynchia to be used with `aggregate()`? Tried it, it produces a django error  (I listed the result under "3")

Comment: @Pynchia If used with `annotate()` It appends `group by stats.id` (primary index) to the query, so it doesn't aggregate the whole table.

Comment: in such case, have you tried `Stats.objects.annotate(**fields).aggregate(**calc_fields)` ?

Comment: @Pynchia Still groups by primary id

Comment: yep, sorry for the silly suggestion: `aggregate` expects a function that aggregates the values of a specified field. I am off to sleep now, I'm on the wrong side of the planet :)